# Distinct of two columns grouping on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a count of number of duplicate values on two columns grouping on another column in SQL Server.

Below is a sample scenario I am working on.

```
    DECLARE @mytable TABLE (CampName varchar(10),ID VARCHAR(10),ListName varchar(10))
    INSERT INTO @mytable
            ( CampName, ID, ListName )
    VALUES  ( 'A',   'X',   'Y' ), ( 'A',   'X',   'Y' ), 
            ( 'A',   'Y',   'Z' ), ( 'A',   'Y',   'Z' ),
            ( 'A',   'Y',   'Z' ), ( 'A',   'P',   'Q' ),
            ( 'B',   'X',   'Y' ), ( 'B',   'X',   'Y' ), 
            ( 'B',   'Y',   'Z' ), ( 'B',   'Y',   'Z' ),
            ( 'B',   'Y',   'Z' ), ( 'B',   'P',   'Q' ),
            ( 'B',   'R',   'S' ), ( 'B',   'R',   'S' )
```

This would result in the following table.

```
 CampName   ID  ListName
-------------------------------------
      A     X     Y
      A     X     Y -- Duplicate Record
      A     Y     Z
      A     Y     Z -- Duplicate Record
      A     Y     Z -- Duplicate Record
      A     P     Q
      B     X     Y 
      B     X     Y -- Duplicate Record
      B     Y     Z
      B     Y     Z -- Duplicate Record
      B     Y     Z -- Duplicate Record
      B     P     Q
      B     R     S
      B     R     S -- Duplicate Record
```

I need the output as follows:

```
CampName   dupcount
-------------------
A            3
B            4
```

Basically, I need to figure out the number of duplicate (ID,ListName) for each CampName irrespective of what the duplicate values are.

Let me know if I can clarify something else in this regard.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT CampName, SUM(cnt) AS dupcount
FROM (
  SELECT CampName, COUNT(*) - 1 AS cnt
  FROM @mytable
  GROUP BY CampName, ID, ListName
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS t
GROUP BY CampName
```

The inner query uses a `HAVING` clause to filter out non-duplicate entries. It also calculates the number of duplicate records per `ID, ListName`. The outer query simply sums the number of duplicates.

Comment: Both most robust (no edge case failures) and performant (not concatenating fields allow use of index scan rather than table scan, if the appropriate index exists) answer here...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple way to get the results you want:

```
select t.campname, count(*) - count(distinct t.listname) as num_duplicates
from @mytable t
group by t.campname;
```

The logic is that `count(*)` counts all rows.  `count(distinct)` counts the number of distinct lists.  The difference is the number of duplicates.

EDIT:

Giorgios makes a good point.  However, the data looks like the `id` and the `name` contain the same information, so only one appears to be needed.  If you have to use both, many databases would let you do:

```
select t.campname, count(*) - count(distinct t.id, t.listname) as num_duplicates
from @mytable t
group by t.campname;
```

But not SQL Server.  Instead, concatenate them together:

```
select t.campname,
       count(*) - count(distinct concat(t.id, ':', t.listname)) as num_duplicates
from @mytable t
group by t.campname;
```

Comment: Only works if the `id` field is completely redundant.  In the example data that appears to be the case, but in the wording `number of duplicate (ID,ListName) for each CampName` it appears that it's not redundant...

Comment: I think `distinct` should consider *both* fields, not just `listname`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the distinct number of combinations of `ID` *and* `ListName` need to be subtracted from the total count for each `CampName` group to get the correct result.

```
SELECT t.CampName,
       COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT 'ColOne' + ID + 'ColTwo' + ListName) AS dupcount
FROM yourTable t
GROUP BY CampName
```

This query employs a trick, which is concatenating the `ID` and `ListName` columns, which are both text, to effectively form a pseudo-group.  The need for this is that `DISTINCT` only works on a single column, but you have two columns which need to be considered.

**Reference:** [Quora: In SQL, how to I count DISTINCT over multiple columns?](https://www.quora.com/In-SQL-how-to-I-count-DISTINCT-over-multiple-columns)

Comment: The concatenation is dangerous;  `'X' + 'XY' == 'XX' + 'Y'`  Even adding a separator is insufficient; `'X' + ',' + ',Y' == 'X,' + ',' + 'Y'`.  To be robust would require a search and replace to 'escape' any occurrences of any used separator.

Comment: @MatBailie We can also append an identifier for each column which we expect to be unique (e.g. `ColOne` for the first column, `ColTwo` for the second column).  Then your example would become `ColOneX + ColTwoXY != ColOneXX + ColTwoY`

Comment: Indeed this is unlikely, but it's still not 100% robust;   `'ColOne' + '12' + 'ColTwo' + 'XXColTwoXX' == 'ColOne' + '12ColTwoXX' + 'ColTwo' + 'XX'`

Comment: @MatBailie No, it's not reasonable to expect your last example.  So you're saying that `ListName` could have an entry called `XXColTwoXX`?  Really?

Comment: yes, that's why in my solution, I preferred an operator in between concatenation :)

Comment: In my experience `#### happens`.  And since there are solutions that neither have edge-case-failures nor obfuscate indexes *(nested aggregation)*, I don't see the merit in this as an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

There is a little bit vagueness in the question.

If you believe all of your `ID` and `ListName` combinations are always equal, the below query works for you:

You can simply do this by using `DISTINCT` inside your `COUNT`

```
SELECT CampName, COUNT(DISTINCT ListName) UniqueCount
FROM @mytable
GROUP BY CampName
```

If you suspect, the combination may not be equal all the time, you need to consider counting the combination of both `ID` and `ListName` columns.

> This assumes a concatenation operator `|` which will not be present in
>   any of the two columns.

```
SELECT CampName, COUNT(DISTINCT ID+'|'+ListName) UniqueCount
FROM @mytable
GROUP BY CampName
```

If you are concerned about counting duplicate number of rows

```
SELECT CampName, COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT ID+'|'+ListName) dupCount
FROM @mytable
GROUP BY CampName
```

An alternative, I think

```
;WITH Temp AS
(
    SELECT CampName, ID, ListName, COUNT(*) UniqueCount 
    FROM @mytable
    GROUP BY CampName, ID, ListName
)
SELECT CampName, COUNT(UniqueCount) count 
FROM Temp
GROUP BY CampName
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. I.e. you can do `COUNT(DISTINCT ListName)`.

Comment: No, and you can even do `COUNT(DISTINCT((((ListName)))))`, if you want to.

Comment: I fail to see how any of the two queries can produce the required results. The user wants to count *duplicate* `ID, ListName` pairs. These queries seem to yield some sort of the opposite result.

Comment: the first answer assumes both `id` and `name` combinations are always equal, so any one in the DISTINCT should work; the second one assumes opposite, so a combination of `id` and `name` generates unique count

Comment: @techspider - This has the same issues as commented on TimeBiegelstein's answer, if the concatenated values can contain `|`...  `'X|' + '|' + 'Y' == 'X' + '|' + '|Y'`

Comment: you are absolutely correct; disclaimer added for now

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for at least commenting on this answer as well :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - ha ha ha :) see OP doesn't even care to update his question with what his expectations and we are all struggling to give him correct answer in every aspect; I believe it may not be appropriate for us to spend more time to make it pass every test case :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I'm just slowly getting through the answers, I'm slow and distracted by that awful `work` stuff ;)  *(Sorry for mis-typing your name above...)*

Answer (score 3):

You can also retrieve same result with CONCAT it is more reliable

```
SELECT CampName, 
    COUNT(ListName)-COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(id,ListName)) tot 
FROM #tmp 
GROUP BY CampName
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, analyse the SELECT statement, the WITH clause is not important to the logic:

```
WITH input_data AS (
  SELECT 'X' AS x, 'Y' AS y FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X' AS x, 'Y' AS y FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X' AS x, 'A' AS y FROM DUAL
)
SELECT input_data.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY x, y) - 1 AS numer_duplicates
FROM input_data
;
```

Comment: Needs one independent result per CampName.  By the time you deal with that you end up with the nested aggregation answer supplied by GiorgosBetsos.

Comment: @MatBailie yup, just using an analytical function as an alternative solution.

Comment: My point is that this alternative solution doesn't do what the the OP asked.  The OP requires a count of duplicates *Per CampName*.

Comment: @MatBailie I got that part, just don't think OP needs to be spoon-fed and can figure out that last small step on his own but maybe I'm just over optimistic.